# Wrong ResultsPerPage output items number

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

As you can see on this [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&relatedToVideoId=LBQ2305fLeA&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&fields=items%252Fid%252FvideoId%252CpageInfo&_h=2&) if the request is with **resultsPerPage=n it returns n-1 items**

Comment: You can check this [blogpost](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3t1urc/youtube_data_api_searchlist_items_array_is/), it says that the `totalResults` are just an estimate, and are not actually accurate. You may get up to the amount of items specified, but there is no guarantee that you will get exactly that. Your best bet is to capture as much as you can, and scan for data using a different time range.